# Django, кнопка записи в таблицу

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Здравствуйте, новичок в Django, необходима помощь, как вывести возле каждой строки *ClientAdmin list_display* кнопку, которая записывала автоматически данные в таблицу *Jurnal* т.е. к примеру пришел клиент > нажали кнопку > и для данного клиента записались в таблицу *Jurnal*

есть модели

```
class Client(models.Model):
    client_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    client_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    client_familia = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    pol = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=POL)

class Jurnal(models.Model):
    poseshenie = models.AutoField(unique=True, primary_key=True)
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    data_poseshenia = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    time_poseshenia = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

admin.py

```
class ClientAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display = ('client_id', 'client_name', 'client_familia', 'time_poseshenia', 'button')

def button (self, obj)
      ....
```

вот, примерно такого, что-то должно получится, то есть по клику автоматически записать время в таблицу Jurnal, то что пришел именно этот клиент
[image: 1]]

Comment: И откуда данные брать-то?

Comment: @andreymal по клику автоматически записать время в таблицу Jurnal, то что пришел именно этот клиент